# ios Realm Swift get all children for a parent entity

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a one to many relationship on my model,

using Realm, how to get all children for a specific parent entity?

ProductsDao.allObjects() have a a relationship to do a predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to have the one to many relationship this is the model for the parent entity:

```
import Realm

class Supplier: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var phone = ""    
    dynamic var products = RLMArray(objectClassName: ProductsDao.className())
}
```

then to get the "products"

> products = supplier?.products

Comment: Correct, you just need to get your supplier object: `let supplier = Supplier.allObjects().firstObject()`

`println(supplier?.products)`

If you're only using Swift, I recommend using RealmSwift instead of bridging Objective-C Realm

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your parent object you can get its children with [relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships)

For example

```
class Person: Object {
    ... // other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

Now let's say we have our Person object called "jim", we can just do

`jim.dogs //Get all children of jim`

Comment: Poor Jim, his children are dogs.